# Kendo UI grid CSS not reflected after deployment through Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines, kendo-grid, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, kendo-angular-ui

We are deploying a DotNet with Angular UI template application through Azure pipeline to an App Service. Few pages having Kendo UI grid where its search icons are not placed properly. But if deploy manually through Visual Studio, it displayed properly. Please anyone let me know what will be the reason and solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To narrow down the cause to your issue, I have several factors to confirm with you. **1.** What the dotnet sdk version is your .csproj is referring to? **2.** What's the os of your pipeline agent (windows-2022, windows-2019, etc)?  **3.** Have you tested to run your pipeline with [selfhosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops)? **4.** You could refer to this post to see if you are effected [Upgrade of .NET agent for Azure Pipelines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/upgrade-of-net-agent-for-azure-pipelines/).

Comment: [1] Target Framework is 4.7.2 [2]windows 2019 [3] We are using self hosted agent only [4]. Agent version is 2.213.2

Comment: Hi VKD, thanks for your feedback, and could you share the latest status of your issue? Any progress?

Comment: Issue still exists.

Comment: I edited my earlier post, and have you checked the tools version in vs and azure devops pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

**updated on 12/5**

Given that you managed to build the project correctly via VS directly, but not through Azure DevOps, I suggest that you could have a detailed check with the tools your builds were utilizing via Visual Studio and Azure DevOps, keep them in same version and test to build the pipeline again.

Comment: we are using scanning tools which are not accessible in MS hosted agents. So we are using self hosted agent which is windows 2019